# Hosted Subversion backups

Tags: hosting, svn

Does anyone know of any companies out there that provide hosted Subversion backups?

Basically my company would like to replicate our Subversion repositories to a 3rd party hosted Subversion service. We'd like our internal repository to remain the primary host, but have the 3rd party service act as a sort of slave server that we could easily fail over to if need be (i.e. we would just have developers create a new check-out off the 3rd party hosted Subversion server and they would only have lost X hours of work).

I've looked at a few hosted Subversion services already, but from what I've seen, they all expect to be serving as the primary host with repository backups replicating to your internal server, which is the inverse of what we desire. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I run a backup script on an off-site server every night.  Since `svndump` supports incremental dumps, it's pretty straightforward to make nightly incremental dumps and weekly/monthly full dumps.

Answer (score 1):

Get a shell account somewhere and use svnsync.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could put in a commit hook that will duplicate the delta between the "master" and "slave" servers.  However, I'd suggest a more simple method.

Get yourself a generic Unix "slice" somewhere -- slicehost.com, or something like it.  You only need get one large enough to cover your data, the memory is really fairly unimportant.

Then you can either periodically rsync your main repo onto this slave box, or you can put in some sort of clever on-commit-trigger-a-rsync hook.

That said, however, Subversion allows a great deal of flexibility in working without a net, so if your developers can live "solo' for a few hours while you recover your main box, that might be fine.  That's entirely your decision there.

I know I would miss my svn repo greatly if it were to vanish.